# How to get the one of the column value based on summation of first column values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a  Customer class:

```
        private int _id;
        private int _value;
        private int _dynamicColumn;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerId"); }
        }

        public int Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Customername"); }
        }

        public int DynamicValue
        {
            get { return _id + _value; }
            set { _dynamicColumn = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerAddress"); }
        }
```

In View Model :

```
ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(paremer =>
                {
                    var customeList = SampleMVVM.Service.Service.GetAllCustomers();
                    Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(customeList);
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Customers");

                });
```

Now the third column is the Sum of Col1 + Col2 . But I want Col3 should have summed value of Col1 only .In this case 897.

Trying to do that on property getter but wont be feasible as won't be having values for all the columns .

[image]

On button click following code is being called:

```
 var customerRecords = default(IEnumerable<Customer>);

            try
            {
                //string[] names = new string[] { "Steve", "Zones", "Ram", "RaOne", "Chacha", "GOne", "Subhen", "Mithilesh", "Annapurna" };
                Random ranomizer = new Random();

              
                customerRecords = new List<Customer>(
                    from index in Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
                    select new Customer
                    {
                        ID = ranomizer.Next(35,100),
                        Value = ranomizer.Next(12,89),
                      //  DynamicValue = this.
                    }

            );
```

Can I do anything here?

**Edit:**
I don't want Dynamic Values as _id + _ value. Instead I want Dynamic Values as the the summation of values of 1st column only

Comment: Can you explain _Dynamic Values as the the summation of values of 1st column only_? Each row should have sum of all other rows?

Comment: Show us a sample output you expect, based on the data you already shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to do this using Element Binding and using Converter. So my XAML now looks like:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Name="dataGrid1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DynamicValue" Binding="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1,Converter={StaticResource columnConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Purposefully set Auto Generate to False to add converter to third column.

Now Converter finds rows of the 1st column only and sum it up.

```
 class FirstColumnConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DataGrid dg = value as DataGrid;
            var totalItems = dg.Items.Count;
            int summedValue = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < totalItems-1; i++)
            {
                    var currentItem = (Customer) dg.Items.GetItemAt(i);
                    summedValue += currentItem.ID;
            }

            return summedValue;   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a custom customer class

```
public class CustomCustomer
{
    public Customer customers { get; set; }
    public int Sum
    {
      get
      {
        return customers.Select(v => v.ID).Sum();
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can bind your DataGrid with Path=Customers.ID, Path=Customers.Value, Path=Sum
using a

```
new ObservableCollection<CustomCustomer>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand what You want to accomplish.

If You want to have a sum of first and second value in your third value you need a property like:

```
public DynamicValue
{
    get
    {
        return this.ID + this.Value;
    }
}
```

and if first or second value is changed (in property's setter) You must also call:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("DynamicValue");
```

Comment: You are answer has already been assumed in my question with code snippet. I want the sumation of values in 1st column only, not the summation of all the coumns

Comment: OK then, Have You already found a solution?
If not - You should create a property not in your Customer class but in Your ViewModel. The property would sum all your needed values. Bind it with a RelativeSource FindAncestor binding and it should work.